# How to automatically resize cells to fit 4 per line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view were I'm looking for a method to find out how big the cells can be to fit 4 cells per line (on that specific screen size) and use that size on all of the cells. I have a reusable cell that I use on the rest of the cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
extension LevelSelectController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

// Collection view flow layout setup
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Compute the dimension of a cell for an NxN layout with space S between
    // cells.  Take the collection view's width, subtract (N-1)*S points for
    // the spaces between the cells, and then divide by N to find the final
    // dimension for the cell's width and height.

    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 4
    let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 0
    let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross

    return CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0.0, 0.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```